# Не удается войти в аккаунт восстановления windows

Tags: windows

Такая проблема, у меня что то с ssd-шником. При запуске windows меня перекидывает в восстановление windows или же выдает экран смерти. Главная проблема в том, что я не помню пароль от своего аккаунта, и не могу понять от чего этот аккаунт. Если Майкрософт, то я уже поменял пароль и попробовал ввести, все равно выдает неверный пароль. Что делать в данной ситуации?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если есть ПК друга то можно подключить твой ссд как допольнительныйт настроив это в Биосе и загрузиться через его hdd и очистить ссд либо же установить винду на твой ссд лишь форматируя системный раздел если не хочешь потерять файлы.

Во всех случаях прийдёться винду накатывать.
Я так 3 раза винду сносил и ничего.